# How to use same macro to read all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook which already has a macro say "covert". It has two worksheets. First includes configurations (variables) required to run macro and second includes rows (data) on which macro is applied. On first sheet there's one button on-click of this rows are converted into JSON. I checked configuration of this button, 'convert' macro is assigned to it.

Now, I want to make a copy of second sheet which will have similar data and I want to use same macro to read this newly created sheet with slight change in macro.

As soon as I copy sheet with data, I can see macro is also duplicated.

To make macro to decide which sheet should be read, I've added a row in first sheet and then I am adding below code to fetch config.

```
Dim configSheet As Worksheet
    Set configSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Configuration")
    
    With configSheet
        VAR_SHEET = .Range("B8").value
```

Then selecting particular sheet using below code.

```
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(VAR_SHEET)
```

Now, the problem is even after making changes in macro, it is always reading first sheet instead of considering variable.

Comment: If the macro will ***ONLY*** run when that particular worksheet is visible, you can use `ActiveWorksheet` (as in `With ActiveSheet`). But this really asks the question of what is the use-case and what does the user expect?

Comment: I want whatever sheet name is given in configuration that should be read not active sheet. And behaviour should be same. Onclick of button macro should run

Comment: You can do a quick debug check by temporarily adding `Debug.Print "VAR_SHEET='" & VAR_SHEET & "'"` and check to make sure an extra space hasn't crept into the sheet name entered in B8. You can also check after the `With` statement: `Debug.Print "with sheet name='" & .Name & "'"` and see what you're getting.

Comment: _As soon as I copy sheet with data, I can see macro is also duplicated._ - is your code in the sheet module rather than its own module (e.g. Module1).  From the code you've provided I can't see a reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Check the button in the copy of the sheet - are you sure it's pointing to the macro in the copy, or does it still point to the original code ?  When you copy a sheet with code like that, any buttons on the sheet do not "auto-adjust" to call code in the copy: they still call the same subs as they did originally. (assuming non-activeX button)

Answer (score 0):

When you copy a sheet with code like that, any buttons on the sheet do not "auto-adjust" to call code in the copy: they still call the same subs as they did originally (assuming non-activeX button).

Any buttons on the sheet which call code in the sheet module will need to be re-linked to the code in the copy.